# Terminal only shows up as a black window

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on a Lenovo Ideapad, and whenever I try to open a terminal window, only a black box appears, and the menus have thick black borders and the nofification box is also black.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Screenshots, please.

Comment: Can you post the image? That would be helpful to know what are you getting.

Comment: I've added one.

Comment: Can you output your error log? Do you have the correct graphics card driver installed? Can you drag the terminal window down further? Or at least shrink the width? The title bar could be out of view and you aren't seeing the output. What happens when you type and hit enter in the box? Does it do anything?

Comment: Yes, try typing `ls` into the terminal and hitting enter. Do you see anything?

Comment: I've tried everything, but I cannot produce a visible error log. It's just black altogether.

Comment: What kind of graphics card do you have? Nvidia? AMD?

Comment: I have Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) graphics

Comment: can you open xterm?

Comment: Yes, does that do the same thing as the normal terminal?

Comment: yes, hmm i think this is a graphics card issue

Comment: Do you get any screen tears when using Firefox or Chrom(e|ium)? You stated you have a Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) gfx card. How do you know this? Is this the spec on your computer or is this what Ubuntu is telling you in Details?

Comment: That is what it says in the details. I have never gotten any screen tears.

Comment: Ok, chances are you don't have the correct graphics card installed. What is the make and model of your computer? I have a GTX750Ti and before I installed the correct driver it says it's an Intel in the Details due to the driver it's using. So we need to identify your graphics card to install the correct driver. Run : `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12` and update your question to show the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41918/discussion-between-jeremy-and-gradon-hutchinson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to an incorrect graphics driver.

First run:

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

To see what type of graphics card you actually have.

Since you have an Intel Graphics card and on 15.10, install the updated driver using [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If all goes well, and if `glxinfo` is installed, typing in a shell:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

will print the driver type and version with the PPA custom string.

Do a reboot and this should solve your issue.