# Terminal / Programs black screen

Tags: command-line, screen, radeon

When I try to run a program, the program screen turns to black.

It occurs also when I do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the Terminal, it's all black color.

I haven't installed anything and the last thing I did was turn off the computer.

The system runs Ubuntu 16.0 with AMD Radeon graphics drivers.

Comment: I think you have the same problem as here discussed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/793625/terminal-only-shows-up-as-a-black-window

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore your `.bashrc`
Start xterm shell `Alt + F2` the type command `xterm -e sh`

Then Type the commands:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
source .bashrc
```

Comment: Not working :/, , I just realized that when I reboot my PC a WARNING/ERROR message appears after rebooting.

Comment: what is the error saying,you should update your answer

Comment: Error :  RADEON 0000:04:00.0 VCE INIT ERROR (-22)

Comment: did you try the suggestion of Andi S